# -- function-call with completion URLRequest - JSON

Tags: json, swift, urlrequest, completion

i did read a lot about functions with completion-handler, but now i have a problem how to call this function (downloadJSON) in the correct way. Which parameters do i have to give in the function and handle the result-data (json) in my own class, where the function was called.

This is the code from David Tran. Hi makes wonderful tutorials, but in the code there is no call of this function.

```
let request: URLRequest
lazy var configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
lazy var session: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: self.configuration)

typealias JSONHandler = (JSON?, HTTPURLResponse?, Error?) -> Void

func downloadJSON(completion: @escaping JSONHandler)
{
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: self.request) { (data, response, error) in
        // OFF THE MAIN THREAD
        // Error: missing http response
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : NSLocalizedString("Missing HTTP Response", comment: "")]
            let error = NSError(domain: DANetworkingErrorDomain, code: MissingHTTPResponseError, userInfo: userInfo)
            completion(nil, nil, error as Error)
            return
        }

        if data == nil {
            if let error = error {
                completion(nil, httpResponse, error)
            }
        } else {
            switch httpResponse.statusCode {
            case 200:
                // OK parse JSON into Foundation objects (array, dictionary..)
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
                    completion(json, httpResponse, nil)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    completion(nil, httpResponse, error)
                }
            default:
                print("Received HTTP response code: \(httpResponse.statusCode) - was not handled in NetworkProcessing.swift")
            }
        }
    }

    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let Xcode help you. Type `downlo` and press return. Xcode completes the function

[image]

Press return again and you get the parameters

[image]

You have to replace the placeholders with parameter names for example

```
downloadJSON { (json, response, error) in
     if let error = error {
         print(error)
     } else if let json = json {
         print(json)
     }
}
```

Note:

There is a fatal type mismatch error in your code: The result of the `JSONSerialization` line is `[String:Any]` but the first parameter of the completion handler is `JSON`

Comment: Hi @vadian, thx. Coding this your way works, but the result of json is an error: expression produced error: error: /var/folders/jx/tcglx0y92y51qlyf7n5fd1_c0000gn/T/expr13-d41d2a..swift:1:65: error: use of undeclared type 'JSON'
Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer<JSON>(bitPattern: 0x12b6fab50)!.pointee)
Is this your note of the type mismatch. What is do there?

Comment: `JSON` belongs to the third-party library `SwiftyJSON`. You have to add and `import` it. But nowadays (Swift 4+) you are encouraged to use the built-in `Codable` protocol. The type mismatch is just a type mismatch.

Comment: OK. You mean `JSON?` is a SwiftyJSON class or method and i have to import it with cocoapods for example? In my last class this code works fine and i can parse JSON very good. `                  let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray ` I Have defined the result as NSArray. And this way  i can work with the JSON data.

Comment: Don't use `NSArray/NSDictionary` in Swift. You throw away the type information. Use native types. As I said state-of-the-art to decode JSON in Swift 4+ is `(De)codable`. It's built-in and it's more efficient than any other parsing third-party library.